# Using regular expression to capture data and save it in a variable c#

Tags: c#, regex

My string consists of valuable data such as an email and subject but there are spaces between them. What I wanted to do was to store the value of the email(any character and ending with.com) into a variable using regex. I am a total newbie when it comes to this. What I came up with the pattern is `^From:\S.com$` but that doesn't seem to work. I am trying to match it using a 3rd party website regex101.

**I need help with:** match it with any character that ends with .com, or basically an email address but it doesnt match the spaces. [Sorry for my english if it's very bad]. I need to take 4 variables ..From,To,Cc and Subject.

***UPDATE:*** credits to CinCout for helping me get the proper regex for From,To and CC. However in the subject part , it is also getting the body. So what I did was I just cropped the body and put it in another string so the regex made by CinCout will work. Please feel free to answer , what I need to do and modify CinCout's regex for subject that will not include the body string too.

My string:

```
From:                                         trial@trial.com 

To:                                               trial@trial.com 

Cc:                                               trial@trial.com 

Subject:                                     Protecting Information and Data Privacy
```

`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`

Comment: `\S+:\s+(\w+@*.+?.+) ` (Regex.Matches -> Group[1], if you have `\n` at the end of each line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern, which only is tried for the From section, does not escape the `.` character.

Try this:

`From:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*To:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*Cc:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*Subject:\s*([\s\S]*)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1RiXZW/6)

Comment: just a minor problem with the subject part of the regex, there is information containing under the subject part and it is also capturing those strings. What will I modify in the regex to not capture those strings?